# jQuery plugin overwrite option

Tags: jquery

Unfortunately I am stumbling upon an issue with jQuery plugins.
I made a small plugin to facilitate building bootstrap modals.

The options for the plugin look like this:

```
defaults = {
    modalName: "",
    size: "md",
    title: "",
    body: "",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            class: 'btn btn-primary',
            value: 'Save'
        },
        cancel: {
            class: 'btn btn-default',
            value: 'Cancel'
        }
    }
};
```

But I want the value of the confirm button to differ for some pages. I thought I could just do this:

```
$( 'body' ).CreateModel ( {
    // Different settings
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            value: 'Save & exit'
        }
    }
});
```

But unfortunately, this completely purges the default object and it only leaves `buttons.confirm.value`. Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the jQuery function `.extend`, You can pass true as first parameter that allow a *deep merging*.

You have to change the line `this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;` to :

```
this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options) ;
```

See an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/n5BKk/

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick. Will mark this as the answer in 4 minutes ;)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us your implementation of how you're working with `defaults` and the object passed in arguments, respectively, but you would be able to solve this problem using [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

Something like this:

```
$.fn.CreateModel = function(options) {
  options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
  ....
};
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using this template: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.basic.plugin-boilerplate.js